# while exporting data to excel from sql using openrowset getting error

Tags: sql-server, excel, openrowset

I am getting error while exporting data from SQL to already created `.xlsx` file. I used `openrowset`.

It works fine most of times, but when the data comes in of the field as a large string, while inserting in excel it shows error as:

> the statement has been terminated , string or binary data would be
>   truncated.

Data gets inserted in table but while inserting in excel this error comes.
Please help me find the solution.

Comment: usually happens when the data you are entering into a field is too long for the properties set for that field. Check your excel sheet for the cell formatting

Comment: While exporting data using openrowset  the data size per field allowed is

Comment: The only time this message is shown is when data being entered into a field is too large for the field it is being placed into. The place you should look at is your excel sheet. unlike transfering to a new file, the datatype will have already been set within the current file.

Answer (score 0):

So, going form SQL Server to Excel, you can do many things.  Check out thins link:

https://www.excel-sql-server.com/excel-sql-server-import-export-using-vba.htm#Introduction

Also, here is some VBA code to move data from SQL Server to Excel:

```
Sub ADOExcelSQLServer()
     ' Carl SQL Server Connection
     '
     ' FOR THIS CODE TO WORK
     ' In VBE you need to go Tools References and check Microsoft Active X Data Objects 2.x library
     '

    Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim Server_Name As String
    Dim Database_Name As String
    Dim User_ID As String
    Dim Password As String
    Dim SQLStr As String
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    Server_Name = "EXCEL-PC\EXCELDEVELOPER" ' Enter your server name here
    Database_Name = "AdventureWorksLT2012" ' Enter your database name here
    User_ID = "" ' enter your user ID here
    Password = "" ' Enter your password here
    SQLStr = "SELECT * FROM [SalesLT].[Customer]" ' Enter your SQL here

    Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Cn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & Server_Name & ";Database=" & Database_Name & _
    ";Uid=" & User_ID & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";"

    rs.Open SQLStr, Cn, adOpenStatic
     ' Dump to spreadsheet
    With Worksheets("sheet1").Range("a1:z500") ' Enter your sheet name and range here
        .ClearContents
        .CopyFromRecordset rs
    End With
     '            Tidy up
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Cn.Close
    Set Cn = Nothing
End Sub
```